# Laplace Transform of power of an integral

Tags: laplace-transform

We know: laplace transform of $\int_{0}^{t}f(x)\,dx$ with respect to s is $\frac{Laplace\,transform(f(t),\,s)}{s}$

What is laplace transform of $(\int_{0}^{t}f(x)\,dx)^{m}$ ?

Comment: It matters what $f(x)$ is because the Laplace transform doesn't converge for all functions.

Comment: Suppose $f(x)=1-e^{-\alpha x}$

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you want to do this:
$$
\int_{0}^t f(t)dt \to \frac{F(s)}s\\
f(t)g(t) \to \frac1{i2\pi}\int_{\sigma=-\infty}^\infty F(\sigma)G(s-\sigma)d\sigma\\
f^2(t) \to \frac1{i2\pi}\int_{\sigma=-\infty}^\infty F(\sigma)F(s-\sigma)d\sigma\\
f^n(t) \to 
\frac1{(i2\pi)^n}
\int_{\sigma_2=-\infty}^\infty 
...\int_{\sigma_1=-\infty}^\infty 
F(\sigma_1)F(\sigma_2-\sigma_1)...
F(s-\sigma_n)d\sigma_1...d\sigma_n
$$
Finally:
$$
\left(\int_{0}^t f(t)dt\right)^n \to 
\frac1{(i2\pi)^n}
\int_{\sigma_2=-\infty}^\infty 
...\int_{\sigma_1=-\infty}^\infty 
\frac{F(\sigma_1)}{\sigma_1}\frac{F(\sigma_2-\sigma_1)}{\sigma_2-\sigma_1}...
\frac{F(s-\sigma_n)}{s-\sigma_n}d\sigma_1...d\sigma_n
$$

The integrals are calculated on the ROC with $\sigma_i$ constant for each step.